# Why doesn't sunlight kill vampires in "Being Human"?

Tags: being-human

In *Being Human* the vampire Mitchell can go outside in sunlight, though he needs to wear sunglasses.

**Does that mean that the myth about vampires combusting in sunlight is not necessarily a solid fact in that universe?**

Comment: Eh, he could be asking exclusively for "in the world of *Being Human*" on the question, although the title does not make that clear. Of course, sunlight killing vampires was something introduced for the film, *Nosferatu*, so it is not part of the original myth, q.v. Dracula walks around in sunlight in Bram Stoker's novel.

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vampire#In_modern_fiction - vampiric vulnerability to sunlight appears to be a modern (i.e 20th century) invention that first came from the movie *Nosferatu* but actually has no basis in folklore.

Answer (score 2):

In Being Human, it seems that the reason to discard the "vampires can't go out in the daytime" myth was largely an out-of-universe one. Simply put, filming at night is considerably more expensive than filming during the day due to the need for lighting and more expensive cameras.

Series maker Toby Whithouse covered this exact question in a [blog post](http://www.bbc.co.uk/blogs/legacy/beinghuman/2010/01/toby_answers_your_series_two_q.html)

> **Karen Hollis asked if I've been watching True Blood and how I think the vampires in that compare to the vampires in Being Human.**
>
> *I love True Blood! They have a much more traditional approach to vampires - can't be seen in daylight etc. Our decision to make
>   Mitchell 'immune' to sunlight was because otherwise a third of our
>   lead cast wouldn't be able to do any daytime exteriors. That would
>   have a huge effect on the production and storylining, which the makers
>   of True Blood don't have to worry about. Partly because their budget
>   is probably 4 times ours, but also because theirs is much more of an
>   ensemble show, dealing with the entire community.*

The [Vamping it up Special](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BIjr9PL-IlA), filmed for the start of Season 3 on BBC3 offered a selection of "rules" to help new viewers and mentions an in-universe reason why John goes out in the sun, in short he's happier in the dark but keen to be more human and that means going outside during the day.

[image]